# CSS SVG Clip Path positioning - start bottom left

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have a div which I am applying an svg clip path to.  It is basically putting a consistent angled edge at the left side of the div.  The svg clip path is oversized as it will apply to different heights of div's.
The clip-path positioning starts at the top of the div so it get's clipped off at the side.
Is it possible for the clip path to start at the bottom left of my div to the angle always starts at the bottom left of the div.

My current html is:

```
<div class="box">

</div>


<svg width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
    
    <clipPath id="sideimgclip"  transform="translate(0 0)">
    <polygon class="a" points="0 686.89 396.58 0 1200 0 1200 686.89 0 686.89"/>
    </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g class="b"><polygon class="c" points="1200 686.89 0 686.89 0 0 1200 0 1200 686.89"/></g>
</svg>
```

And the css:

```
.box{ width:650px; height:450px; background:#c00; 
        -webkit-clip-path: url(#sideimgclip);
        clip-path: url(#sideimgclip);

}
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mmc501/85tfb12L/2/

Comment: transform: scale(1, -1); or similar I guess.

Comment: That would work if I knew the height of the div every time - the height is going to vary.
e.g. translate(0 -230) brings to close to starting at the bottom left in the example in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the CSS [polygon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/polygon) function as a source of the `clip-path`, you can use units and the `calc()` function when defining the shape. Do this:

```css
.box {
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 400px calc(100% - 800px), 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
.example {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box example"></div>
```

As long as the `px` values ensure the second vertex computes to a point outside the bounding box, the result is a consistent-angled left edge.

Comment: Ah - that's excellent - I had already been playing with the polygon but wasn't getting a consistent angle.  Key point being starting at bottom left, and as you say going beyond the bounding box. Thanks!